# Android studio showing non readable language

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

I was getting this error in the android studio so i tried uninstalling it and again in installation process i get the same non readable language. The language in rest of the PC is readable i.e English. What could be the reason?

Comment: it looks like a bad build (mangled strings), as Previous and Finish buttons look OK .What version is it? Have you tried installing a different version? You may also want to check the JDK version on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Go your android studio -> lib

[image]

Check .jar file start with resources

[image]

In my directory, only has resources.jar and resources_en.jar .
You could try delete others and reopen AS.